# Use foreach-loop in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

So this is my foreach-loop

```
foreach($statusMessageResult as $row){
    $row['username']=$db->getUsername($db->getUserNameById($row['posterID']));
    $results[] = $row;
    echo "Status from: " . $row['username'] . " ID: " . $row['statusID'] . "<br>" . $row['dateTime'];
}
```

Which works without problems. But now I want to have the same in smarty. 
So I thought I'm going to do this in the .php file

```
$smarty->assign('results', $results);
```

and this in the .html file

```
{foreach from=$results item=statusID}
    id: {$statusID}<br>
{/foreach}
```

But it tells me

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in F:\xampp\htdocs\FinalYear\smarty\templates_c\ab89063f543bf0a8fe20c45b89aad63b616cd7c5.file.home.html.php on line 86
Array
```

Well the problem seems clear: I have an array and want to use it as a string, whiich isn't allowed. But how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
{foreach from=$results item=result}
    id: {$result.statusID}<br>
{/foreach}
```

If you want user name : `{$result.username}`

Ref: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach

Comment: id: {$result.statusID|stripslashes}

Comment: @DeppG : Is that really needed ? It will be a int field in Db usually rite?

Answer (score 0):

`statusID` is an array, get value by key name like that:

```
{foreach from=$results item=statusID}
    id: {$statusID.username}<br>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: id: {username} makes no sense to me, I think he wants the id ;)

Comment: no problem: `{foreach from=$results item=user}
    id: {$user.statusID}<br>
{/foreach}`

Answer (score -1):

`$statusID` seems to be an array :)

changing

```
{foreach from=$results item=statusID}
    id: {$statusID}<br>
{/foreach}
```

to

```
{foreach from=$results item=statusID}
    id: {$statusID['statusID']}<br>
{/foreach}
```

should solve it